# Efficient Way of Storing Trivial Data on PHP, MySQL and JS Site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I am working on a site that runs on PHP and MySQL. At the moment, I am developing some features that utilize JS and jQuery. In particular, I am building a slider using jQuery for the frontpage that is controllable from CMS. For the time being, I am just storing the images for the slider in a directory and parse that directory for .jpg and .png files using PHP.

Since I am also needing to store other information about the images like their sequence, should I use JSON for that and still keep the images in a basic directory? Or should I try to store both images and information in the database? I do not envision there being more than 20 images on this slider.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: While this isn't really a "bad" question, the problem with it, is that it's very broad and opinion based, and as a result, will likely be closed.

Comment: I realize this. Where does one go if he falls between the binary world of Stackexchange and Short questions of Quora?

Answer (score 1):

I would store in the database image file name + the rest of the info needed( alt ,title, position in the slider, if image is active/inactive in the slider) but not the image itself. Then it gets easy to manage this info about the images ...
And when it comes to build the gallery  you can send a json to the browser and make the browser do the work to build the necessary html... or you can build the html server side based on the info you have on the database.

Comment: Would you still store the image in a basic directory, then? How does JSON come into play here?

Comment: Yes I would store the image in a basic directory. I would build the json  based  on the information I have in the database about the images... and send that json info to the user browser ... and use javascript to read the json and build the html. Or if you prefer you can read the info from the database and build the html for the slider on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. It is pain in the a@@ to deal with storing / retrieving MySql queries and encoding / decoding them to JSON just for something simple as a slider.

There are many libraries which does exactly that. Many wordpress plugins create yet another table for this purpose which is why WP is such a bloated platform.

**It boils down to your expectation.** If you want to make your code modular or can afford SSD servers for database, go ahead and make another PHP class for that. But keep in mind that even with SSD Servers, the processing time increases for every PHP->HTML echo. You don't want your website to end up like WP, do you ?

**The other 'quick-fix' options** is to use something like **HTML5 localstorage**, a simple JSON File which can be retrieved by client directly using JQuery (I use angular) instead of PHP  <-> MySql poking their finger in between.

On a side note, I would suggest that you go for SSD Servers only because of latency issues. Digital Ocean is a great service (5 USD a month) and so is Amazon RDS. We had to switch over to Digital Ocean from Godaddy shared hosting for a mobile backend and never looking back (it is the fastest and most consistent SSD Storage currently available here in India, 250ms from Frankfurt).

Hope this helps.